# É possível fazer num unico projeto o PhoneGap junto com Asp.Net MVC 5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, apache-cordova

Gostaria de saber se existe a possibilidade de fazer um **Solução no Design de DDD** com duas *View Ports*, sendo uma para aplicativo móvel usando **PhoneGap** e a outra **MVC 5**.

Quero fazer um sistema de Gestão de atividades que vai ser acessado pelos meus líderes. Poderão fazer inclusões via **Intranet** ou quando tiverem em alguma reunião pelo **Celular**.

Gostaria de fazer um **Domínio** igual para ambos conforme o **DDD**, mas o banco sei que vai ser diferente, usando o SQL Server e outro banco Javascript, exemplo **SQLite**.

Vejo muitas exemplo dizendo que isso é possível mas não encontrei uma forma ou dica que possa validar esse conceito.

Poderiam me ajudar?
Obrigado!

Comment: Rapaz, vá com calma. Você parece estar perguntando sobre coisas que não tem domínio e sua pergunta parece estar ampla demais. Para começar, MVC só vai até o 2 (você por  acaso não quis dizer asp.net-mvc-5 ?)

Comment: Sorry, isso mesmo queria dizer que era aps.net MVC 5. sobre a pergunta eu não tenho dominio mesmo do assunto por isso pedi ajuda. Eu já fiz um projeto em DDD mas o meu lideres querem que agora o que esta asp.net MVC 5 funcione tb para Mobile. acho que agora fui claro. Desculpa.

Comment: Vou deixar a resposta para alguem de .net, mas, creio que seja melhor ao invez de você usar sqlite, aproveitar a base de dados / regras de negócio do que já está feito e conversar via REST.

Comment: Achei muito boa essa dica teria alguma exemplo Usando Rest para Phonegap, amigo meu disse a mesma coisa estou pesquisando aqui se encontrar algo vou postar para comunidade. Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Gostaria de saber se existe a possibilidade de fazer um Solução no Design de DDD com duas View Ports, sendo uma para aplicativo móvel usando PhoneGap e a outra MVC 5.

Existe sim. Para configurar seu projeto para múltiplas *View Ports*, certifique-se de invocar o [`DisplayModeProvider`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.webpages.displaymodeprovider(v=vs.111).aspx) na inicialização do seu sistema, arquivo Global.asax.cs:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        ...

        var displayModes = DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes;

        ...
    }
}
```

Feito isso, produza suas *Views* para Phonegap utilizando o sufixo `.Mobile.cshtml`. Por exemplo, se você quer customizar o layout do sistema, diferenciando o layout da *View Port* principal da *View Port* móvel, crie dois arquivos:

- /Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml
- /Views/Shared/_Layout.Mobile.cshtml

Isto vale também para toda e qualquer *View* do seu sistema: não apenas para o Layout.

Sua aplicação já tem capacidade de detectar o *User Agent* (o navegador do dispositivo e o tipo de dispositivo) e chamará a *View* correta para cada caso.

## Gostaria de fazer um Domínio igual para ambos conforme o DDD, mas o banco sei que vai ser diferente, usando o SQL Server e outro banco Javascript, exemplo SQLite.

A parte de *Models* do seu projeto já segue o DDD. Não é necessário qualquer mudança adicional.

Não é necessário usar duas tecnologias de banco. Apenas o SQL Server é suficiente para produzir o que você precisa.

Comment: Muito obrigado Cigano, novamente sempre com boas resposta ajudando todos. 
vlw.